# openshift ssl route configuration with wild card certificate

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

we use custom DNS configuration in openshift master, which uses a wild card certificatefor SSL. So when I am configuring  secure route objects, I usually provide below options in route.yml,

```
tls:
caCertificate: <ca certificate>
certificate: <wildcard cert>
key: <wildcard cert key>
...
```

The problem I am facing currently is, since we use wild card certificate in the master for custom domain,  for each application route.yml I am placing the cert and key. Any user who has access to the project can see these cert and key, that is not ideal and secure. Is there a way in route.yml, I can directly specify the master cert path? that way content of the cert and key are not exposed to the users

Comment: Are you talking about a separate custom DNS domain, or the default wildcard domain for applications in the cluster when you don't specify a hostname? If you don't specify a hostname and use OpenShift to generate it, just select edge termination and OpenShift will worry about the certificates for you. The user doesn't need to seem them.

Comment: instead of using the default nip.io, we use something like,  abcd.com. we do use the host configuration in route, and sets it something dynamically like                                           
      host: <application-name>-route.abcd.com

Comment: Btw, above solution mentioned by Graham works just fine. Thank you